# How to specify managed package test class name during deployment?

Tags: apex, unit-test, managed-package, deployment

I have the following ant task:

```
<target name="deployUnpackagedCheckOnly">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username.prod}" password="${sf.password.prod}" 
        sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="600" 
        deployRoot="unpackaged" logType="Detail" checkOnly="true" 
        rollbackOnError="true" allowMissingFiles="true" pollWaitMillis="30000"  
        testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests">
    <runTest>SBQQ.QuoteDocumentTriggerTests</runTest>
  </sf:deploy>
</target>
```

Here I am trying to specify a test class from steelbrick managed package.

When I run this task, I see that salesforce is ignoring the namespace and trying to find a test class with that name and thus not executing the managed package test class I wanted:

Here is the screenshot showing where salesforce ignoring the namespace:

[image]

Below quote is from [Force Migration tool guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy_run_specific_tests.htm?search_text=runspecifiedtest) that we can specify test classes from managed package:

> The test class name can include a namespace prefix. Add a namespace
>   prefix if your organization has a namespace defined or if the test
>   class belongs to a managed package. For example, if the namespace is
>   MyNamespace, specify the test class as MyNamespace.TestClass1.

What am I missing here?

Comment: are you adding namespace of your package or your own org namespace?

Comment: I am adding namespace of the package in which test class is there. Our org doesn't have namespace.

Comment: there will be namesspaces for managed package components like objects, apex class etc. Make you you append it to the test class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a false alarm. Salesforce was indeed executing the test case from Managed Package even though in the screenshot it was not showing the namespace prefix.

I reached out to Steelbrick support and they mentioned that I should be executing a different test class as this one does not cover the trigger that I was trying to deploy. So I gave the correct test class name from managed package and I was able to deploy the trigger that I wanted to deploy.

Comment: Might want to circle back and accept this answer.